# AEM used only for textual content, but need dynamic calculations in between

Tags: api, dynamic, aem, calculation

I am using AEM 6.1 just as a textual content management, which will publish out the pages and they will be consumed by a different front end.

So, I'm just publishing copy. What if I want to include some mathematical calculated nos in between.

Eg: Wonder Woman is the highest grossing movie of the year. It made --calculation- say 600 million-- dollars.

If the entire text is edited in AEM, but just the 600 million part should come from some other API, which has some logic for calculation. How can we achieve this?

The problem is, we do not have any API calls to and from AEM. It is just going to be used for content editing and publishing.

I was thinking, if there is a way, I can add some placeholder in the place of the calculation and the frontend logic will use that to call APIs and plug the nos.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The number of possible ways to achieve this makes this a very broad question. You could have a look at [_Knot.x_](http://knotx.io/). It can act as an integration layer where AEM is just a source of static, content-editable HTML templates managed by the marketing teams and the actual API is provided by a set of modules deployed using [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/). Knot.x can further use a templating engine such as handlebars to fill the static HTML with data obtained from the services.

Comment: What kind of server is the "different frond end"? The issue you have is quite common, if the web-site integrates various backend systems.